# How to create proxy process which redirects stdin to child?

Tags: c, linux, bash, pipe, stdin

I want to make a proxy process which opens the real one.

Like if I rename linux's `espeak` to `espeak_real` and my app to `espeak`.
`espeak` opens `espeak_real` and I get the output.

I want to make possible to:

- Prints it's STDIN to the console
- Prints it's STDIN to another process's STDIN
- Prints the second process's STDOUT

I'm trying to do it in C (I guesss it's possible with raw bash too).

Comment: maybe this question will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7383803/writing-to-stdin-and-reading-from-stdout-unix-linux-c-programming

Answer (score 1):

I don't exactly understand what you do, but it seems like a combination of `fork`, `exec`, `pipe` and `dup2` should do it.

`app` can use `pipe` to get a pair of file descriptors, connected with a pipe (what's written into one is read from the other).
Then it can fork, and the child can `exec` `app_real`.
But between `fork` and `exec`, `dup2` can be used to change any file descriptor you want to 0,1 and 2 (but close the real 0,1,2) first.

Short code example:

```
int pipe_fds[2];
pipe(pipe_fds);
if (fork()==0) {
    // Child
    close(fds[1]);    // This side is for the parent only
    close(0);         // Close original stdin before dup2
    dup2(fds[0],0);   // Now one side of the pipe is the child's stdin
    close(fds[0]);    // No need to have it open twice
    exec(...);
} else {
    // Parent
    close(fds[0]);            // This side is for the child only
    write(fds[1],data,len);   // This data goes to the child
}
```

Comment: linux doesn't have exec(), also I want to write all of STDIN to the child.

Comment: Linux has multiple varieties of `exec`, the simplest is `execl`. If you do nothing with `stdin`, the child can just read it (the parent should close it). You can play the `dup2` games with other fds.