# returning a buffer in c

Tags: c, winapi, buffer

I have a couple of questions.
I need to write a program(winapi) that will create a buffer of a fixed size, then append strings to it and returns it. 
1. Is it even possible for "main" to return a buffer?
2. How should I create, append string and return it?

I am not new to C, but I have very little experience with buffers and strings handling.
Thank you!

Comment: Yes, `main` can/may return _integer_ but not _buffer_, but first of all try something to write by yourself. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions here. Please be aware that we do not provide _from-scratch_ coding service. Please show us what you've tried already, how it failed and we might be able to help.:-)

Comment: Too add on to what @SouravGhosh said, this is not a place where we don't put in effort and demand answers. Put in some effort, and we will put in effort to help

Comment: @SouravGhosh, I was looking for some good link for OP about what `main` returns, then I will inform you about the update. Cheers!

Comment: It sounds like you either have misunderstood the problem description or the problem description is unclear. (It's common for beginners to confuse *return* and *output*, so that might be the issue.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Is it even possible for "main" to return a buffer?

No and you shouldn't. [What should main() return in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c)

> 2. How should I create, append string and return it?

```
char aString[FIXED_SIZE];
memset(aString, 0, sizeof aString);
strcpy(aString, "This is a string");
```

Answer (score 0):

main in c only returns an integer, which is used to indicate the success or failure of the program.

See [What should main() return in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c)

What you might want to consider is writing to stdout ([What does it mean to write to stdout in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16430108/what-does-it-mean-to-write-to-stdout-in-c)) or direct to a file.

Comment: I don't need the program to write to STDOUT, but thanks :)