# Why does calling write() with stdin result in output?

Tags: c, posix, stdin

I can understand why writing to stdout and stderr would have output, but why stdin?

```
#include <unistd.h>

int
main()
{
  const char test[] = "test test test\n";
  write(STDIN_FILENO, test, sizeof(test) - 1);
  return 0;
}
```

EDIT: For those who want to give it a try, you can [compile and run the program here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMcDBmcVR0UmtQQjg)

Comment: This has been answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7383803/writing-to-stdin-and-reading-from-stdout-unix-linux-c-programming

Comment: Suppose that you `fork()` and have created a pipe between the child and the parent, then you can write to the parents `stdin` from the child, and to the childs `stdin` from the parent. So writing to `stdin` is not undefined for sure, as to why the shell outputs it, I have no clue.