# read() and write() not working as expected

Tags: c, stdout

This is something I did as part of simple experimentation;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int fun()
{
 int d=10;
 write(1,(int*)d,sizeof(d));
}

int main()
{ 
 int x;
 fun();
 read(1,(int*)x,4);
 printf("x=%d\n",x);
 return 0;
}
```

As you can see I am trying to access value of `d` in `fun()` function via the IO stream (IO files) `stdout`; I tried using `stdin` as well but the thing is `x` value is not changing. (I tried in an online IDE.) But as per my thought stream, it should change to value of `d`.

Can anyone help me see why it is not doing that?

Comment: Please show us an example of input and expected output.

Comment: Even if you fix up the calling sequences (pass pointers to `read()` and `write()`), you are not going to be able to read what `fun()` wrote.  Yes, you often can read from standard output — but unless you've done something fancy (I/O redirection, etc), reading from standard output is the same as reading from standard input, meaning it will read what you type at the keyboard.  What you wrote to standard output will go to the screen (unless you've done some I/O redirection) and will not become part of the input data.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler How to do that ?

Comment: @SurajJain: How to do what?

Comment: @SurajJain To `read()` what you did `write()` you need something where they are both connected to the same thing, for example a pipe, a socket or a file. So I suggest you `open` a file, `write` to it, `seek` back to the beginning and  finally `read` what you have written.

Comment: I'm guessing you meant to use the **addresses** of `d` and `x`, rather than to cast them to pointers: `write(p[0],&d,sizeof d)` and `read(p[1], &x, sizeof x)`.  Assuming that `p[]` has been populated using `pipe()`, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

read and write require *pointers*. In your case it is `&d` and `&x`.  Casting `int` to `int*` usually makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

Replace line :

```
write(1,(int*)d,sizeof(d));
```

with :

```
write(1, &d, sizeof(d));
```

and line :

```
read(1,(int*)x,4);
```

with :

```
read(1, &x, 4);
```

---

***Reason for this modification :***

As you can see in [this reference for read()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html), the prototype for function `read` is :

```
ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count);
```

and respectively the prototype for function `write` is :

```
ssize_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count);
```

as shown in [this reference for write()](https://linux.die.net/man/2/write).

Therefore, both functions require a pointer as their second argument. So you must pass a *memory address* to them.

---

***NOTE :*** You try to make a pointer from an integer by casting it to `int*`. Actually, `int*` indicates a pointer in the case of a declaration or in a prototype, but when you use `*` in front of a variable's name, it indicates the *contents* of this variable. The symbol `&` is used to indicate the variable's address.

Answer (score 2):

First, correct call to `read()` and `write()` would include getting a pointer to your variable and passing it.

Second, you read and write from stdout (file descriptor 1), as opposed to your description. It doesn't matter if you read from `stdout` instead of `stdin`, according to 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7680234/2543937

Third, it's better to use the `unistd.h` definitions (`STDOUT_FILENO`, `STDIN_FILENO`, etc), instead of fd numbers directly.

```
int d, x;
write(STDOUT_FILENO, &d, sizeof(d));
read(STDOUT_FILENO, &x, sizeof(x));
printf("x=%d\n", x);
```

In regard to what I think was your initial idea: when you read from `stdout` (or `stdin`), the data comes from the keyboard input, and not from what was printed to the screen earlier - so value of `d` should not make it to `x`.

Comment: thanks for the correction, edited the answer. other answers only talk about "first"point of my answer. there's also second, third, and attempt to actually answer my interpretation of the asked question

Comment: you're now reading from `STDOUT_FILENO`, might point that one out :D

Comment: that's what the code in original question does, and that's also what "second" point of my answer is talking about