# Difference between user input and write(0, input, strlen(input))

Tags: c, input, signals

I'm getting user input in a main reading loop, and I want to get custom input if ctrl-c is pressed.
But it seems that there's a difference between user input and some string wrote in the standard input with `write(0, foo, strlen(foo);`.

Here's a small program that shows that:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void ctrlc_handler(int signal)
{
    write(0, "abc", 3);
}

int main(void)
{
    char    buf[5];

    signal(SIGINT, ctrlc_handler);
    while (1)
    {
        write(1, "> ", 2);
        memset(buf, 0, 5);
        read(0, &buf, 4);
        printf("Read: %s", buf);

    }
    return (0);
}
```

And an exemple of output:

```
> Hey
Read: Hey
> ^Cabc
Read:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this answer:

[Writing to stdin and reading from stdout (UNIX/LINUX/C Programming)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7383803/writing-to-stdin-and-reading-from-stdout-unix-linux-c-programming][1])

Seems that we can't write to stdin, even if in my case it seems to work and the write function doesn't return -1